# How to insert html in to svg element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

element is formed but as if there exists within theHave this markup

```
<g id="g-svg_el_obj921" style="top: 300px; left: 550px;">
  <circle r="95.12" fill="rgb(50, 149, 196)" class="some_class" id="svg_el_obj921" priority="4" position="300_550" cx="550" cy="300"></circle>
</g>
```

i need to insert some `div` element into `g` or `circle` element, so i do this:

```
$('g').each(function(){   
    var feel_el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'div');
    var $feel_el = $(feel_el);

    $(this).append($feel_el);
});
```

element is formed but seems like not exist... Can anybody help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All foreign content must be a child of a `<foreignObject>` element in SVG. Additionally a `<circle>` element can't have rendered children, but a `<g>` element can.

So you'd have to change your function so that it firstly creates a `<foreignObject>` element, gives that element a width and height and then creates a `<div>` element and makes it a child of the `<foreignObject>` element, so that you create markup that looks like this.

```
<g id="g-svg_el_obj921" style="top: 300px; left: 550px;">
  <circle r="95.12" fill="rgb(50, 149, 196)" class="some_class" id="svg_el_obj921" priority="4" position="300_550" cx="550" cy="300"></circle>
  <foreignObject width="100" height="100">
    <div>
    </div>
  </foreignObject>
</g>
```